# How to get SQL to use where criteria when using group by and like statements

Tags: sql, view, group-by, sql-like

I have a SQL view that contains a group by. I am trying to select from the view using a like. The column I am selecting on is indexed but SQL insists on creating a temp table with all the rows in the table and then filtering on the where criteria. (slow) How do I get it to filter FIRST?

**Example**:

**View definition**:

```
SELECT ListCode, SUM(CASE
    WHEN ListStatus = 'A' THEN 1
      ELSE 0
      END) Active
FROM ListParticipation
GROUP BY ListCode
```

**Select**:

```
SELECT *
FROM ListParticipationView
WHERE ListCode like '%ReallyCoolList%'
```

Incidentally, if I use like criteria without the beginning wildcard the SQL plan does show the filtering occurring before the group summarization.

Comment: My best guess is that your real solution is to work around passing a list into a `LIKE` statement for what I assume is a [Many-to-Many Relationship](http://www.tekstenuitleg.net/en/articles/software/database-design-tutorial/many-to-many.html).

Answer (score 2):

**Your criteria is not SARGable, that is it cannot use an index.**

Using `LIKE` with `%` at the beginning of the comparison string guarantees a table scan.  SQL has to check the whole field in every row to evaluate for a match.

If your `ListCode` is a very long string, maybe you should make it an int which is the `PK` in a lookup table.  Then you could evaluate:

`WHERE Listcode IN (1, 3, 4, 6)` and make use of an index.

Answer (score 1):

It's not filtering first because the beginning wildcard is preventing the index from being used.  Basically, it has to search the *entire* string - so it still has to search **every single row**, because the index on a `char` or `varchar` usually starts from the first character... This would be roughly equivalent to wondering why a multiple-column index isn't being used, when your selection criteria only restricts based on the second or third column, not the first.

If you have repeating `ListCode`s (as would apparently be the case), consider extracting them to their own table, then placing the id of the new table as `listCodeId` in the `ListParticipation` table (and replace the index too).  If you have a smart enough optimizer, it'll find all the `listCode`s in their table that match the given wild-carded string (should be unique, so please have a unique constraint), then use that to query the fk index on `listCodeId`.  Should be much more performant.

Comment: I'm actually okay with an index scan.  I think my confusion lies in the fact that if I do a : SELECT ListCode, SUM(CASE
    WHEN ListStatus = 'A' THEN 1
      ELSE 0
      END) Active
FROM ListParticipation WHERE ListCode like '%ReallyCoolList%'
GROUP BY ListCode                                                             This performance is alot better. It's doing a full table scan FIRST getting only the rows it needs to summarize and then doing the grouping. Not sure what I need to do differently to get the view to do use the same sort of plan.

Comment: You're not getting an index scan, you're getting a table scan.  And I suspect that your RDBMS isn't resolving the correlation between the `where` predicate and the grouped column in the view - doing it as one query allows it to resolve this.  I'm not up on how much some of them can resolve this, though.  Still recommending pulling out `ListCode`s to their own table, though.

Answer (score 0):

I see you've learned why views are often a bad idea. It gets much worse if they call other views. If the SQL statement directly accessing the table is faster, use that. But don't use a where clause with a like statement that has a wildcard as the first character. Doing this for anythign other than a throw-away query indicates you need to use a differnt technique such as:

1. youneed to fix the design
   or
2. you need to use fulltext indexing

If you are storing data such as 'test, mytest, another stupid test' in one column and using the like clause to find all values of 'mytest' then you need to normalize your tables and store the data correctly.

If you have users who are searching for terms they may not know the exact name of (say a long formal airport name like 'Ronald Reagan National Airport' and the searchmight be for 'National Airport') then use full text indexing instead.

If you are putting the % in front for no particular reason, then stop doing it.